# LARAVEL - How to create an indirect relation between 3 models

Tags: laravel, eloquent, models

I have 3 Models: User, Pet and Clinic.

Let's assume the tables: users, pets and clinics. The relation is, one user can have more than one pet, and one pet only have one clinic.

On the table "Pets" i have a FK to the user_id and another one to the clinic_id.

I want to do something like:

```
$user->clinics();
```

on the User model to return all the distinct clinics associated with the user. Now i can only do:

```
$user->pets()->with('clinics);
```

but i want to return only the distinct clinics.

User modal:

```
public function pets()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Petable\Models\Pet', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

Pet modal:

```
public function clinic()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Petable\Models\Clinic', 'clinic_id', 'id');
}
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: what do you mean by `return only the distinct clinics`? can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Maybe something like `$user->pets()->with('clinics')->distinct()->get()`

Comment: I want to return all the clinics related to the user through the pets. For example: If i have 2 Pets both on the same clinic, $user->clinics(); should return 1 clinic. If i have 2 pets on 2 different clinics, it should return 2 clinics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should be sufficient:

```
public function clinics()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Petable\Models\Clinic', 'user_pets')->distinct();
}
```

And then this allows you to call

```
$user->clinics();
```

Comment: Many thanks, it's working with your last solution :) The "little" problem is that    it's returning the same clinic twice.. any way to prevent duplicates ?